# Python sorting list with multiple keys and negating for some of them

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of tuple in python and I would like to sort it first the decreasing order of value(int) and if it matches the increasing order of word(str)

```
data = [(1, u'day'), (2, u'is'), (2, u'lunny'), (4, u'the')]

data.sort(key = lambda x: (x[0], x[1]), reverse=True)
```

The above sorts by decreasing order of value but fails to handle sorting by increasing order of str(2nd value in the tuple).

Does anyone have suggestion for a workaround on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leave `reverse=False` but just negate the first value

```
>>> data.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[0], x[1]))
>>> data
[(4, 'the'), (2, 'is'), (2, 'lunny'), (1, 'day')]
```

Comment: thanks, this was really helpful, can we generalize this to any number of secondary key, i meant if i had k element in my tuple some of them needs to be sorted in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

You could also run `sort` twice, taking advantage of it being stable ([see doc](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)). Maybe you find this to be more explicit:

```py
>>> data = [(1, u'day'), (2, u'is'), (2, u'lunny'), (4, u'the')]
>>> data.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])
>>> data.sort(key = lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
>>> data
[(4, 'the'), (2, 'is'), (2, 'lunny'), (1, 'day')]
```

When sorting by `x[0]`, the previous order (ascending by `x[1]`) is preserved.